# Iterate through multi-row array of objects in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I'm very much new to scripting and in need of some help. I have this array of objects:

```
[ 'Gender', 'Customer Code', 'From', 'To', 'Transport Code' ] [ 'M', 'XX123', 'DAL', 'RSW', '555A' ] [ 'F', 'XXXHXH,XXA', 'DAL', 'RSW', '5A,HDSJNDSJ' ]
```

which I read from a csv file through the fast-csv api. I'm finding difficulties in iterating through the objects as they don't have a key. Also, I have few multi-value fields enclosed within `""` which need to be formatted as separate rows/records. How do I do it so that I get the data in the following format as a `csv file`?

```
Gender,Customer Code,From,To,Transport Code
M,XX123,DAL,RSW,555A
F,XXXHXH,DAL,RSW,5A
F,XXA,DAL,RSW,5A
F,XXXHXH,DAL,RSW, HDSJNDSJ
F,XXA,DAL,RSW, HDSJNDSJ
```

Below is my code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

csv
 .fromPath("journey_details.csv")
 .on("data", function(data){
     var count = 5;
     var elements = '';
     for(var element of data) {
         while (count > 0) {
             elements += element + ','
             count--;
             if(count == 0) {
                 elements += '\n';
                 fs.appendFile('output.csv',elements,function(error) {
                    if (error) {
                      console.error("write error:  " + error.message);
                    } else {
                      console.log("Write Successful!");
                      count = 5;
                    }
               });
             }
         }
     }
 })

 .on("end", function(){
     console.log("Task Complete...");
 });
```

But it doesn't seem to work out. Please enlighten...

Comment: Have you tried to do it yourself?

Comment: @KoshVery : please have a look at the update above

Comment: It seems that you're repeating the same `element` 5 times within the `while` loop. So the output looks incorrect to me. What is `data` and what is `element` in  the `for` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses recursion to loop over every index and create a path according to each value.

*This approach doesn't follow the desired order, however, generates the possible combinations.*

```js
function loop(arr, acc, path, index) {
  for (var i = index; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var split = arr[i].split(',');
    if (split.length) {
      for (var s of split) {
        var innerPath = loop(arr, acc, [...path, s], i + 1);
        if (innerPath) acc.push(innerPath);        
      }

      return null;
    } else {
      path.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  acc.push(path);
}

var names = [ 'Gender', 'Customer Code', 'From', 'To', 'Transport Code' ];
var array = [ [ 'M', 'XX123', 'DAL', 'RSW', '555A' ],
              [ 'F', 'XXXHXH,XXA', 'DAL', 'RSW', '5A,HDSJNDSJ' ]];

console.log(names.join());
array.forEach((a) => {
  var acc = [];
  loop(a, acc, [], 0);
  acc.forEach(aa => console.log(aa.join()));
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```